# Fire Grouping Commands does not work as expected

Tags: python-3.x

I follow [The Python Fire Guide](https://github.com/google/python-fire/blob/master/docs/guide.md) and execute the script in Grouping Commands.
The program is shown below:

```
import fire

class IngestionStage(object):
    def run(self):
        return 'Ingesting! Nom nom nom...'

class DigestionStage(object):
    def run(self, volume=1):
        return ' '.join(['Burp!'] * volume)

    def status(self):
        return 'Satiated.'

class Pipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ingestion = IngestionStage()
        self.digestion = DigestionStage()

    def run(self):
        self.ingestion.run()
        self.digestion.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fire.Fire(Pipeline)
```

However, nothing happened after executing the command:

```
$ python3 example.py run
```

I run this program on ubuntu 16.04 with python 3.5.2.
The version of fire package is 0.1.3.
Has anyone met this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for catching this. The reason `python3 example.py run` doesn't print anything is that Pipeline.run doesn't return anything.

If you instead update the Pipeline.run method to:

```
def run(self):
    return [
        self.ingestion.run(),
        self.digestion.run(),
    ]
```

then you'll see the desired output:

```
$ python example.py run
Ingesting! Nom nom nom...
Burp!
```

We'll have to update the Guide.